# ASP.NET Cannot initiate instance object of a Class I created

Tags: asp.net

So I created a class file Persons to my website project and placed this in a folder called `App_Code`.

But now in my `default.aspx.cs` I cannot seem to create i.e. `Persons test = new Persons();`

Says

> Type or Namespace Persons not found

This is my persons class so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
{
    public class Persons
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string DisplayFullName()
        {
            string info;
            info = "FullName is: " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
            return info;
        }

        public void setData(String sLine)
        {
            this.FirstName = "Test";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the appropriate Namespace in your Code behind(default.aspx.cs):

```
using WebApplication1.App_Code;
```

Comment: Yeah didnt work I get error there to i.e adding to default.aspx using WebApplication1.App_Code; I get error under App_Code saying namespace does not exist

Comment: When I try and do public namespace WebApplication1.App_Code, I get an error under public which says a namespace declaration cannot have modifiers or attributes

Comment: @Akhil What? `public namespace xxx` ? "Namespaces implicitly have public access and this is not modifiable"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your Person page and your aspx code page are in different namespaces. You cannot resolve type names across namespaces without importing them with the `uses` keyword.

Add

```
using WebApplication1.App_Code;
```

To the top of your default.aspx code behind page.

If you mouse over `Person` where it has the error, you should get a little helper popup that has the option of adding the missing using clause automatically!

If your working purely with an aspx file with no code behind, use:

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.MyNamespace" %>
```

So in your case:

```
<%@ Import namespace="WebApplication1.App_Code" %>
```

Comment: When I try that i.e adding to default.aspx using WebApplication1.App_Code; I get error under App_Code saying namespace does not exist

Comment: @StevieB It should be on your *.cs file, not the aspx html file.  Unless your doing your code all on the aspx file with markup tages. In that case use `<%@ Import namespace="MyProgram.MyNamespace" %>`

Comment: @StevieB I'm only going off the code with the namespace name you listed. This is your problem, poke around the namespace declarations, and made sure that the using clauses are all correct, that's all we can do for you.